# Git Graphical log is not working

Tags: git, github, git-config

I am pretty new to git and I am trying to create a graphical log from an given example in git with this code:

```
git config --global alias.graphlog log --graph --full-history --all --color \ --pretty=format:'%x1b[33m%h%x09%C(blue)(%ar)%C(reset)%x09%x1b[32m%d%x1b[0m%x20%s%x20%C(dim white)-%x20%an%C(reset)'
```

...currently I am not yet understanding all the given parameters in the example.
Is it a git setting issue or something which is wrong with the example code?

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to do 2 things here :
- edit your configuration file
- display the logs

If you just try your command to view the logs it works well :

```
git log --graph --full-history --all --color --pretty=format:'%x1b[33m%h%x09%C(blue)(%ar)%C(reset)%x09%x1b[32m%d%x1b[0m%x20%s%x20%C(dim white)-%x20%an%C(reset)'
```

Then to use the alias `git graphlog` you should do :

```
git config --global alias.graphlog '!git log --graph --full-history --all --color --pretty=format:"%x1b[33m%h%x09%C(blue)(%ar)%C(reset)%x09%x1b[32m%d%x1b[0m%x20%s%x20%C(dim white)-%x20%an%C(reset)"'
```

That will add the command git graphlog to your config file `.gitconfig` but in your example you were missing the quotes and the ! before git, also I had to remove the \ in the middle of your command.